# colour element of a list by looping over another list

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function in python that will take a list B and loop over another list A. if an item in list B is present in list A, it colours it red else ignores it and returns a list A with both coloured and uncoloured text. my code isn't working at the moment.

```
A = ["a", "b", "c", "c"]
B = ["a" "c"]

def color()
  for i in B:
    if i in A:
        print(Fore.RED + i) 

color()
```

Comment: Instead of printing, you need to modify the list item itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use one loop for this.

```
class colors:
    RED = '\033[31m'
    ENDC = '\033[m'

A = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
B = ["a", "c"]

def color():
    for i in A:
        if i in B:
            print(colors.RED + i + colors.ENDC + " ", end="")
        else:
            print(i + " ", end="")
color()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this?

```
A = ["a", "b", "c", "c"] 
B = ["a" "c"]
def color():
    for i in B: 
        if i in A: 
            A.append(Fore.Red+i)
    print(A)
color()
```